# cURL wont download for me?

Tags: macos, download, http, curl

OS X 10.8.3, from a terminal I am executing:

```
$ curl -OCv http://<URL>/<file>.dmg
```

I get (for 2 seconds)

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   222  100   222    0     0  46707      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  108k
```

Then it does nothing. Back to a prompt.

I know the URL is right. It my own domain, public website. I know the file.dmg is right as well, I put it there a few mins ago to test.

I see 222K file on my desktop to, but obviously this is because it failed.

a 3.7gb DMG if that is helpful.

EDIT: I also tried `$ curl -OCvi` same thing occurs.

Comment: What is the actual content of the file on your desktop (open it in your webbrowser)? That 222-byte file looks a lot like an HTTP error reply page.

Comment: What does `curl -v http://<URL>/<file>.dmg >/dev/null` say?

Comment: Alternatively, what does this file contain? Can you `cat` it and see anything?

Comment: What exit code do you get? (`echo $?` after the curl command)

Comment: Perhaps you have some sort of redirect... try `-L` flag.